# How to fill combobox with database values using n tier architecture in c# windows form

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sqlite, data-binding

i write the code to fill combobox with database value. my code is working correctly if this code written on presentation layer. But i want to written this code on data layer. i have 3 project in my solution (UI, BLL, DAL). i want this code in DAL and then call in UI with the help of BLL. how to do that. please help me. here is my code.

How to convert my code into 3 tier architecture.

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(EmployeeComboFills.ecbconn()))
            {
                string CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM User";
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(CommandText, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        CELD_employeename.Items.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
```

how to write this code in 3 tier. OR if someone have better code for do that then please share it. Thanks.

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`  on a Select query?

Comment: `CELD_employeename.DisplayValue = "Name"; CELD_employeename.DataSource = dt;`

Comment: A comboBox needs two Properties set for each ComboBoxEntry: A Value (usually a Databases Primary key) and a DisplayName (A name, Descriptor, string of a lookup table). How you retreive those values and how you use them to Populate the ComboBox are usualyl secondary. But I guess you are hoping for some automatic/helper code to do it for you (wich is not a bad idea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the items to the combobox directly, add them to a list. Assuming that `EmployeeComboFills` is your static DAL class, you can add this method to it

```
public static List<string> GetUserNames()
{
    string CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM User ORDER BY Name";
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(ecbconn()))
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(CommandText, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt.Rows
            .Cast<DataRow>()
            .Select(dr => dr["Name"].ToString())
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Then you can assign it to the combobox with

```
CELD_employeename.DataSource = EmployeeComboFills.GetUserNames();
```

Comment: i get Error of this line " return dt.Rows
            .Select(dr => dr["Name"].ToString())
            .ToList() "

Comment: Apparently the Rows collection does not implement `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, therefore I had to add `.Cast<DataRow>()`

Comment: combobox doesnt any value.

Comment: I made a simple test: `comboBox1.DataSource = new List<string> { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" };`. This works for me. `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` of the combobox must be empty. Also tested `GetUserNames()` with a SqlServer version. Works. Make tests and debug.